# Listing and updating records in db

Tags: database, angular, crud, sql-update

I have an Angular 4 front end that retrieves a list of records from a db and displays them to a user. I allow the user to edit each item by opening a popup dialog, making changes to the data, and clicking a Save button.
There are multiple users but I'm told that it will mostly be one user updating a given record at any one time.

- when I load the records each record has all the data required, so I don't retrieve the record when the user opens the popup dialog (as all the data is already there).
- when I save the data I return a status 200 on successful update and close the dialog - I don't refresh the list of items.

Does anyone see any issues with this approach? One thing I'm thinking is that if they have the initial screen open for a while, some of the records may have been updated by another user.

- should I retrieve the record from the db when the user opens it in the popup dialog?
- should I refresh the list of records after the user updates one and closes the popup dialog?
- is there an easy way to check if a record has been updated in the background while a user was editing the same record

Just looking for best practice or typical approaches to this scenario - tia.

Comment: I do not know what DB you are using but I would suggest taking a look at Firebase Firestore as all the records are Observables and the data acknowledges changes whenever anyone makes a change to it, so you are not fetching all the time.

Comment: Thanks @NicholasPesa but I'm using SQL Server and can't change that unfortunately